# How do I algebraically express a rotated triangle in terms of its original dimensions and its rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a triangle ABC. Rotate it around the origin A by -30$^\circ$ to triangle ADE. How do I algebraically express DJ (the y coordinate of D) in terms of the edges of ABC (the original 20$^\circ$ right-triangle) and/or AGI (the 30$^\circ$ right-triangle)?

The dimensions of ABC and AGI is known, so I could calculate the ratios between their edges but the trig values of 50$^\circ$ is not known.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $AGI$  and $EGH$ are proportional (Thales) :
$$\widehat{HEG}=30° \implies \widehat{DEF}=60°\implies DF = DE\sin(60°)=BC\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Now you only have to find $FJ=HI=GI-GH$

You have $EG=GA-AC$

$AGI$ and $EGH$ are proportional (Thales) and therefore 
$$GH=GI\frac{GE}{GA}$$

In the end, 
$$FJ=GI\left(1-\frac{GA-AC}{GA}\right)=GI\frac{AC}{GA}$$

$$DJ=DF+FJ=BC\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+GI\frac{AC}{GA}$$

Comment: $DGE$ and $ABC$ can't be proportional because $\widehat{DGA} = 80^\circ$ and $\widehat{ABC} = 70^\circ$

Comment: Thanks @stity for putting me on the right track, I got the answer. I'll post it later.

Comment: @dataphile I edited, sorry for the error

Comment: Cool, thanks a million.